# RestEasy returns XML when I ask for JSON

Tags: json, resteasy

I am using RestEasy to hook into an api. I specify that I want JSON back but I continue to get XML... Here is where I define my endpoints

```
@Path("/page.asmx")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface ApiProxy {

    @POST
    @Path("/doc_Get")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    ClientResponse<DocOutput> getDocOutput(@Form DocInput docInput);
}
```

When my service ties to unmarshal the response I get the following error:

```
 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"https://something.com/", local:"ServiceBaseOfDoc"). Expected elements ...
```

I am also registering a JacksonJsonProvider with resteasy. Its as though the header Content-Type: application/json is not being passed...

If I try this same request with curl and use the header content-type: application/json I get json back... why am I getting XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an @HeaderParam to my method and was able to force the correct content type.

```
ClientResponse<DocOutput> getDocOutput(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") MediaType contentType, @Form DocInput docInput);
```